# Is there any approximation in which the double pendulum has an exact solution?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, approximations, integrable-systems

We know that the [double pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) isn't an integrable system, since only energy is conserved versus two degrees of freedom. My question is, does a physical approximation exist, in which the total time derivative of another observable can be 'set' to zero rendering the double pendulum exactly solvable?

Comment: You can take the approximation where the pendulum moves only very little away from equilibrium. I think this is usually called the small angle approximation even for the double pendulum. In that approximation the motion is harmonic. I assume you're looking for something more complicated?

Comment: Yes, you are right; should I edit the question to specify it?

Comment: An unmoving double pendulum would seem to be exactly solvable...

Comment: It sure would; are you suggesting there's no other way of obtaining an integrable system? Is there any way to justify this?